# woocommerce (arg) to get shop_order by product category

Tags: woocommerce

Currently I have a category called 'vou' and would like to just get shop_order under this category. I have tried many combinations and it's not working out. Thank you for reading:

```
   $args = array(
'post_type' =>'shop_order',
'post_status' => array_keys( wc_get_order_statuses() ),
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'orderby'=> 'date',
'order' => 'DESC',
'tax_query' => array(  
    array( 
    'taxonomy' => 'vou'//,
    //'terms' => get_terms( 'product_cat', array( 'fields' => 293 ) ),

    ) 
  )
```

);

How to get shop_order by product category 'vou'?

Comment: Shop orders don't have any categories by default. Do you mean you want to get orders that contain products of a certain category? If so then my first instinct would be to create a taxonomy for the `shop_order` type and add it when the order is created. Then you'll be able to query like above.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Find all your orders and gether orders that have required category. Make new args with post__in attribute.

```
$m_args_all = array(
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'posts_per_page' => 12,
);

$ordr_cat = 654 // id of required cat
$empty_cat = false;

$orders_all_raw = wc_get_orders( $m_args_all ); //find all orders by your args
if (!empty($orders_all_raw)) { 
    $orders_in_cat = []; 
    foreach ($orders_all_raw as $order_raw) {
        $items = $order_raw->get_items(); //get products of order
        if (!empty($items)) { 
            foreach ($items as $item_id => $item) { //loop for products
                $term_ids = wp_get_post_terms($item->get_product_id(),  'product_cat', array('fields' => 'ids')); // get all id of cats in product
                if (in_array($ordr_cat, $term_ids)) { // if required cat in array of gethered cats add order id to array
                    if (!in_array($order_raw->ID, $orders_in_cat)) {
                        $orders_in_cat[] = $order_raw->ID; //add order with required prod cat to array 
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
    if (empty($orders_in_cat)){
        $empty_cat = true;
    }
    else {
        $m_args_all += array('post__in' => $orders_in_cat);
    }

}
if($empty_cat){
    $orders = [];
}
else{
    $orders = wc_get_orders( $m_args_all );
}
```